# can't download file using wget with authentication while being called from php

Tags: php, shell

I've created a small remote download script which downloads remote files to my server using wget.
Now here's how it works:
I have a html form, which the user can enter the URL, destination file name, and optionally username and password to authenticate, in case needed.
The form calls a php script, using AJAX, and the php script passes the information to a shell script.
Now the problem is, the shell script works flawlessly on my local linux machine, but on my server, it doesn't work with authentication(without authentication, it works just fine.)

```
#!/bin/bash

if test $# -eq 2
then
    wget -O "$2" $1
elif test $# -eq 4
then
    wget -O "$2" --http-user="$3" --http-password="$4" $1
else
    wget $1
fi
```

it might be worth mentioning that, I own a shared server.

Thanks

EDIT:
Is it possible that the version of wget installed on the server, doesn't support http authentications???

EDIT 2:
I piped the output of wget to a file like this:

```
wget -O "$2" --http-user="$3" --http-password="$4" $1 | echo >> output
```

but the output is empty, i.e. no messages is being printed from wget!!!
And I did this too, to check if the credentials passed is ok:

```
echo "$3 | $4" >> credentials
```

And it was ok.

And this is the php code which runs the shell script:

```
if(isset($_POST["startdownload"]))
{
    list($url, $dest, $user, $pass) = explode("|", urldecode($_POST["data"]));
    $filelen = file_len($url);
    $freespace = getRemainingSpace();
    //die( "( Free: $freespace, File: $filelen )" );
    if($filelen > $freespace - 10000)
    {
        $result = json_encode(array("error" => true, 
                        "message" => "There is not enough space to download this file. ( Free: $freespace, File: $filelen )"));
        die($result);
    }
    else
    {
            if($user != "NULL" && $pass != "NULL")
            {
                execInBackground("../dl.sh '{$url}' '../{$dest}' '{$user}' '{$pass}'| at now");
            }
            else
            {
        execInBackground("../dl.sh '{$url}' '../{$dest}' | at now");    
            }
            $result = json_encode(array("error" => false, "message" => "Starting download..."));
            die($result);
    }
}
function execInBackground($cmd) 
{
    if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows"){
        pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd, "r")); 
    }
    else {
        exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");  
    }
}
```

Comment: On a security note, i hope you're escaping the vars. Also, why not use cURL? It's much easier also on the HTTP-authentication!

Comment: Well, actually I can't remember why I chose wget over curl. I've recently decided to add the authentication :-). and about escaping, the thing is, i'm the only one who's gonna be using it, so no worries there ;-)

Comment: I guess I used wget, because curl would block the php script, and I wanted something asynchronous, though I'm not sure!

Answer (score 0):

Well, running this script via system/exec/shell_exec or any others, probably going to "block" the rest of the PHP script anyway. But as an answer, check out this: http://www.zarafa.com/wiki/index.php/Using_wget_and_HTTP_authentication_for_supported_downloads

```
wget -O "$2" --user="$3" --ask-password="$4" $1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ChrisH :-). Well, I assure you that there's nothing wrong with: wget -O "$2" --http-user="$3" --http-password="$4" $1 . Since I ran it on my local machine. All I can guess is that either there's a problem with the wget installed there, or since it's a shared server, there's some limitation.

Comment: Do you get any output at all? I.E. can you show me how you execute it in PHP and how you 'fetch' the result? If possible, you should try to run it via SSH on the server itself: that way you have full view of "what" is going on

Comment: Well, the main problem is that it's a shared server, and I can't use ssh. The php code, which runs the shell script, has been included in the question, thanks

Comment: Can't see any actual PHP code in the question? Do you use exec, system, shell_exec, popen?

Comment: I included it, after I added the comment :-D I didn't know that you would look it up so fast ;)

Comment: Haha, i can see it now indeed! Just to try something out: `echo exec($cmd); exit();` It's not nice (hard exit wtf?!) but it's great for debugging these kind of things. It should echo the result, including any errors. Also try it with system and shell_exec functions, perhaps you'll get a different result?

Comment: nahhh! I tried that too, but the message was empty. For now, I have to give up,

Comment: That's too bad.. You could try to ask this at your hosting company. Perhaps they know what's wrong or why it doesn't work. Or, you could convert it all to cURL ;)

Comment: WELL, JUST FORGET ABOUT MY HOSTING COMPANY. and about curl. I can't get the file size with curl. i can get the size of a file that doesn't have auth, but with auth, it just doesn't work.